# C++ Memory Leak Issues

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Ok, so here's the easy way to explain it, the following code is from an SDK for a game of Unreal Engine 3, so most of the code shown was generated by a seperate program and not myself, however I've run into an issue with it and I can't seem to get it solved.

Basically, this is the line I'm calling

```
if (Entity->GetHumanReadableName().Data)
```

The function is causing a very small leak (adds up over a few hours until program crashes) Now I'm using the GetHumanReadableName function just for this purpose, but any function that returns an "FSTRING" will cause a leak, which to me atleast means my FSTRING is leaking, but I can't figure out where.

So I'm hoping to break down each layer and hopefully you guys can figure this out with me?

```
struct FString AActor::GetHumanReadableName ( )
{
    static UFunction* pFnGetHumanReadableName = NULL;

    if ( ! pFnGetHumanReadableName )
        pFnGetHumanReadableName = (UFunction*) UObject::GObjObjects()->Data[ 3859 ];

    AActor_execGetHumanReadableName_Parms GetHumanReadableName_Parms;

    this->ProcessEvent ( pFnGetHumanReadableName, &GetHumanReadableName_Parms, NULL );

    return GetHumanReadableName_Parms.ReturnValue;
};
```

FSTRING Structure

```
struct FString : public TArray< wchar_t > 
{ 
    FString() {}; 

    FString ( wchar_t* Other ) 
    { 
        this->Max = this->Count = *Other ? ( wcslen ( Other ) + 1 ) : 0; 

        if ( this->Count ) 
            this->Data = Other; 
    }; 

    ~FString() {}; 

    FString operator = ( wchar_t* Other ) 
    { 
        if ( this->Data != Other ) 
        { 
            this->Max = this->Count = *Other ? ( wcslen ( Other ) + 1 ) : 0; 

            if ( this->Count ) 
                this->Data = Other; 
        } 

        return *this; 
    }; 
};
```

TARRAY Structure

```
template< class T > struct TArray 
{ 
public: 
    T* Data; 
    int Count; 
    int Max; 

public: 
    TArray() 
    { 
        Data = NULL; 
        Count = Max = 0; 
    }; 

public: 
    int Num() 
    { 
        return this->Count; 
    }; 

    T& operator() ( int i ) 
    { 
        return this->Data[ i ]; 
    }; 

    const T& operator() ( int i ) const 
    { 
        return this->Data[ i ]; 
    }; 

    void Add ( T InputData ) 
    { 
        Data = (T*) realloc ( Data, sizeof ( T ) * ( Count + 1 ) ); 
        Data[ Count++ ] = InputData; 
        Max = Count; 
    }; 

    void Clear() 
    { 
        free ( Data ); 
        Count = Max = 0; 
    }; 
};
```

I mean, I'm sure I have to mess with the deconstructor of TARRAY or FSTRING, but I'm just not sure what I need to do...If you need any more code exerpts please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `free( Data )` needs to be made when the object is destroyed.

Create a destructor in your `TArray` struct that calls `Clear()`:

```
~TArray() { Clear(); }
```

Also, you're going to want to test `Data` to make sure it isn't `NULL` before you `free()` it (and set it to `NULL` afterwards per Rafael's comment).  So in the `Clear()` method change the `free()` line to:

```
if ( Data != NULL ) {
    free( Data );
    Data = NULL;   // edit per Rafael Baptista
}
```

Comment: Also in clear, make sure to set Data to NULL after the free. Or you'll crash if you insert after clear.

Comment: public: 
 TArray() 
 { 
  Data = NULL; 
  Count = Max = 0; 
 }; 
 ~TArray() { Clear(); }

Comment: Thats the correct place for the deconstructor correct?

Comment: Yes, placing it right after the constructor is pretty common.